# Create C++ executable for Ubuntu from OS X

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, ubuntu, 32bit-64bit

I have GCC 4.7.2 and OS X 64 bit. I want to create an executable `exe` file from a `main.cpp` for a friend of mine with Ubuntu 32 bit. I tried with `$ g++ main.cpp -o exe` but he says it doesn't work because I compiled for 64 bit.

How can I compile it for 32 bit?

Comment: It won't work - your friend will need to re-compile the source on his Linux system.

Comment: Like GCC? Try `crosstool`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your friend is wrong. It may well be true that he has a 32-bit machine and you've created 64-bit executables, but even if you compiled for 32-bit (which is done by compiling and linking with `-m32`) there are lots of other reasons it still won't work. Mac OS X and Ubuntu are completely different systems and code compiled for one will **not** run on the other.

Any single build of GCC can only generate code for a single target i.e. a single combination of CPU and operating system.   The GCC on your system is built to target Mac OS X, i.e. it's a native compiler, meaning it generates code for the same system it runs on.

To generate executables for Ubuntu you need a different build of GCC, one built with something like `--target=i686-unknown-linux-gnu`.  If that GCC runs on your Mac then it would be a *cross compiler*, meaning it runs on one system but generates code for a different type of system.

To install and use a cross compiler you also need all the C libraries for the cross target, so you'd need to get copies of the glibc sources and build them on your Mac, using the cross compiler. That is fairly complicated, but there are projects such as `crosstool` and `crosstool-NG` that try to simplify it by providing scripts to do the work.

It would be much simpler to set up a Virtual Machine on your Mac and install Ubuntu in the VM, then use the native GCC from Ubuntu to compile executables for Ubuntu.

It would be even simpler for your friend to do `apt-get install gcc` and compile the source code himself.

Comment: Yeah I think I'm going to compile it on a virtual machine on my Mac. Thanks a lot